# On hover tooltip by using javascript or GWT

Tags: javascript, html, css, gwt

I am create an web application in Google Web Toolkit.
I want to create a On-hover tool-tip on hyperlink. In this tool-tip i need to show the user image, username, her/his designation, and address of that user.

Problem :

1. My problem is to stay that tooltip when i move the cursor from hyperlink to tooltip just like G+ and facebook shows the user information when i move the cursor on any user name it show an toolitp and we can easily from the cursor from username hyperlink to tooltip.
2. Secondly, that tooltip position should be changed dynamically, similar to facebook like sometime that tooltip shows on upper side and sometimes it shows on downside of the username hyperlink.

**NOTE :** i can only use javascript and GWT. No jquery answer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [PopupPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) widget. It has a useful method `showRelativeTo()`, which you can use to show this panel next to your Anchor widget.

You can add your own logic when this popup shows and hides.